# How to hide a ionic modal that shows a list after selecting a value?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a ion-view that shows a list of items in a modal. I want to dismiss the modal once I select an item. I have associated the modal template with a controller using an ng-controller attribute.

How do I dismiss the modal form inside the controller where I will be getting click events ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
$scope.modal.hide();
```

Comment: It works. but is it because I set the $scope of the modal to be same as scope of my current controller ?
What if Iwant to create new scope for the modal ?

Comment: it works becuse you hold the instance in `$scope.modal=modal` . Whatever scope you wanna to use . You will hold modal instance like that.

Comment: How do I pass the selected item from modal's controller to it's the controller that opened up the modal ?

Comment: Are you talking about new directive which will contain modal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple modals, give different names to scope variables..

```
$ionicModal.
    fromTemplateUrl('example.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'  }).
    then(function(modal) {
        $scope.exmapleModal = modal;
        $scope.exmapleModal.show();
        $scope.closeExample = function() {
            $scope.exmapleModal.hide();
            $scope.exmapleModal.remove();
        };
    });
```

Close the modal the same name as 
`$scope.closeExample();`